# How to write common functions for reusing in C

Tags: c

I was trying to write a common function for other files could reuse it, the example as following, I have three files:

The first file: cat test1.h

```
void say();
```

The second file: cat test1.c

```
void say(){
  printf("This is c example!");
}
```

The third file: cat test2.c

```
include "test1.h"
void main(){
  say();
}
```

but when I ran: `gcc -g -o test2 test2.c`
it threw error as：

```
undefined reference to `say'
```

Additionally: I knew this would work:`gcc -g -o test2 test1.c test2.c`
but I don't wanna do this, because the other team would use the server, and I hope them directly use my binary code not source code. I hope that just like we use printf() function, we just need include .

Comment: You did not include test1.c in the compilation step.

Comment: I recommend that you read-up about `make` and `makefiles` so you can learn how your C compiler takes each source file and outputs corresponding `.o` files which are then linked together to form the final output executable.

Comment: yes, I didn't include it. I supposed that the code will be given to other team to use, so they should not know my c code(implementation)

Comment: you need to provide either the source code or a compiled library. It's not magic dust, somewhere there has to be the definition of the function in the program.

Comment: @bolov I hope that just like we use printf(), we incude <stdio.h> then we can use printf(), we do not need to compile printf source code with our source code.

Comment: `printf` is a part of the C library (`libc`) which is linked with your code implicitly. That is why you may be under an impression that simply including a header file makes a function available.

Comment: Adding `#include "test1.h"` in your test1.c file is a good idea. That makes the compiler check for inconsistencies between the header file (which you will provide to your clients) and the implementation file (which you will keep for yourself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build yourself a library from the object files containing your useful functions, and store the header(s) that describe them in a convenient location.  You and your colleagues then compile with the headers and link that library with any executables that use any of those functions.  That's very much the same general mechanism that the C compiler uses to include the standard headers and automatically link with the standard C library.

The mechanics vary a bit depending on platform (Windows vs Unix being the primary distinction, though there are differences between Unix platforms too), and also on the type of library (static archive vs dynamic linked / loaded libraries — also known as shared objects or shared libraries).

In broad outline, for a Unix system with a static library, you'd:

- Compile library object files `libfile1.o`, `libfile2.o`, … using (for example) `gcc -c libfile1.c libfile2.c`.
- Create an archive from the object files — using for example `ar r libname.a libfile1.o libfile2.o`.
- Copy the headers to a standard location such as `/usr/local/include`.
- Copy the library to a standard location such as `/usr/local/lib`.
- You'd compile any code that uses the library functions with `-I/usr/local/include` (if that is not already a standard compilation option).
- You'd link the programs with `-L/usr/local/lib -lname` (you might not need to specify `-L…` but you would need to specify `-lname`).

Answer (score 1):

Including a header file does not make a function available. It simply informs the compiler that the function will be provided at a later time.

You should compile the file with the function into a shareable object file (or a library if there is more than one function that you want to share). Mind the switch `-c` which tells `gcc` not to build an executable file:

```
gcc -o test1.o test1.c -c
```

Similarly, compile the main function into its own object file. Now you or anyone else can link the object file with their main program:

```
gcc -o test2 test2.o test1.o
```

The process can be automated using `make`.

Answer (score 1):

Other programmers can use compiled object files (`*.o') in their programs. They need only to have a header file with function prototypes, extern data declarations and type definitions.

You can also wrap many  object files into the library.

On many systems you can also create the dynamic linked libraries which do not have to be linked into the executable.

Answer (score 0):

you also need to compile test1:
`gcc -g -o test2 test1.c test2.c`.

Comment: hi, thank you, I modified my question, the command you gave me is not I wanted. I hope other programers could use my binary directly.